# Parse table into array

Tags: c#

i have this table:

```
List<string>

 Total HTTP Packets              727       0.004459
  HTTP Request Packets            372       0.002281          51.17%
   GET                             372       0.002281         100.00%
  HTTP Response Packets           353       0.002165          48.56%
   ???: broken                       0       0.000000           0.00%
   1xx: Informational                0       0.000000           0.00%
   2xx: Success                    337       0.002067          95.47%
    200 OK                          331       0.002030          98.22
    204 No Content                    5       0.000031           1.48
    206 Partial Content               1       0.000006           0.30
   3xx: Redirection                 10       0.000061           2.83%
    302 Found                         3       0.000018          30.00
    304 Not Modified                  7       0.000043          70.00
   4xx: Client Error                 6       0.000037           1.70%
    408 Request Time-out              6       0.000037         100.00
   5xx: Server Error                 0       0.000000           0.00%
  Other HTTP Packets                2       0.000012           0.28%
```

i want to parse this table into array (each line into 4 parts) but my problem is the first column because the string length changed.
i tty to split each line with Tab but unfortunately i did dot contain Tabs.
what is the best way to do it ?

Comment: Assuming by `table` you mean items within a `List<string>` then you are going to have to identify / specify a column delimiter for each row. You were on the right track with tabs but if that doesn't work perhaps multiple spaces? Or are your strings padded to a fixed-width? You really need to clarify or help a bit further with the item layout.

Comment: its a List<string>, Tabs didn't work, how to use multiple spaces ?

Comment: `line.Substring(startIndex,length)`

Comment: Regex is a better overall solution (more robust, and more performant on large sets) than substring parsing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a regular expression (Regex class). Regular expressions rock for exactly this reason. Alternatively, if you're getting the input as XML (which it doesn't seem like you are), XPath might work for you too.

I prefer regex, because it's simpler to write. You probably just need to know that `\s` represents empty space. The best place to write it is over at [Rubular](http://rubular.com/), where you can paste your content, type your regex, and see *as you type* how things match.

Comment: i don't have any idea how to split it

Comment: @DanaYeger I won't write it for you, but I would start with something simple, like: `([0-9x:]+)\s([a-zA-Z]+)\s+\(d+)`, this should give you the error code, name, and first column.

Comment: @DanaYeger no worries, let me know if you need more help. If you need regex tutorials, Rubular itself has a nice listing at the bottom of basic stuff.

Comment: this Regex looks confuse, i would happy for some help

Comment: @DanaYeger it souunds like you're not familiar with regex. Google for regex tutorials and use Rubular. This page is usually quite good: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html